# JAVA - Difference between Class class and *.class files?

Tags: java, class, oop, reflection, jvm

There's something I don't understand between *.class files and Class class API. Let's me explain :

I have a file A.java representing a java class :

```
public class A { ... }

Class<?> clazz = A.class;
```

When I compile A.java, I get a A.class file (the byte code).

Is there any relation between the A.class file (bytecode) and clazz which represents the instance class (A.class) ? Are they the same thing ?

Thank you

Comment: "*Is there any relation between the `A.class` file (bytecode) and `clazz` which represents the instance class (`A.class`) ?* - Yes. An instance of `Class<A>` is an object-oritented representation of your type `A`. Just look at the [documentation of `Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) to see what you can do with it.

Comment: `Class clazz` is like variable ( String a ). Which contains what is at `A.class`

Comment: What is the ``instance class``? ``A.class`` gives you an instance of ``java.lang.Class``, which enables you to e.g. use reflection on that class.

Comment: The bytes of .class is loaded into a Class. For the rest Class is an internal Object with structure, and code in the JVM, constants in the constant pool of the JVM,

Answer (score 5):

*.class files are files on the disk, `A.class` is a class object in the memory.

Comment: This points out some differences between the `.class`-files and  and their representation as `Class`-instance. But OP asked for the relation between them, not the differences.

Comment: Part of the question is *JAVA - Difference between Class class and *.class files?*....

Comment: @Turing85 : so if I'm correct about differences :  1) *.class files on the disk represent the java code of the class translated into bytecode. 2) A.class object repsents memory on the heap. Inside A.class object there's memory to store instance variables of this class. Is this correct ?

Comment: @AntonBoarf No. You made it up. The `Class` object contains information *about* the class, not all its instances.

Comment: @EJP But the class object is an object so it lives on the heap. I thought everything related to information about class was on the method area (not the heap).

Answer (score 1):

```
Class<?> clazz = A.class;
```

is equivalent to

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("A");
```

except that for the class literal, `A.class`, the compiler will check that `A` is available and accessible at compile-time, so its availability will be mandatory at runtime. Therefore, you don’t need to catch checked exceptions.

If `A` is not abstract and has a default constructor, you would get the same via

```
Class<?> clazz = new A().getClass();
```

Of course, all these constructs depend on the availability of a class definition for `A` at runtime, which is typically delivered in a class file name `A.class`, but the fact that one of these source code constructs looks similar to the file name has no relevance.

Note that for nested classes, the source code representation and the file name will differ, e.g. when using `Map.Entry.class` to refer to the nested type `java.util.Map.Entry`, the class file’s name will be `Map$Entry.class`. You could also add an `import` statement for this class and refer to it via `Entry.class`, showing that this construct is subject to the standard source code name resolution rules and not connected to the file name of the compiled class.